# MySQL - where clause with a named Arithmetic Operator

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I do have an MySQL table, which contains Inventory of a Warehouse over time. I would like to see the range of the min and max value per Warehouse. This is working fine now:

```
SELECT WAREHOUSE_ID, (max(INVENTORY) - Min(INVENTORY)) as 'Diff' FROM ShopData
group by WAREHOUSE_ID
```

Results in:

```
# WAREHOUSE_ID, Diff
42131733712, 0
42132001360, 0
310572515344, 4
```

When I try to use a "where" clause on the created "diff" column, the result remain the same.

```
SELECT WAREHOUSE_ID, (max(INVENTORY) - Min(INVENTORY)) as 'Diff' FROM d0287d28.ShopData
WHERE 'Diff' = 0 
group by WAREHOUSE_ID
```

It still shows the result as above. But it should only show the first two lines instead.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    WAREHOUSE_ID,
    MAX(INVENTORY) - MIN(INVENTORY) AS Diff
FROM ShopData
GROUP BY WAREHOUSE_ID
HAVING Diff = 0;
```

It does not make sense to refer to your aggregate calculation in the `WHERE` clause, because the grouping process has not even happened yet at that point in the query.

Comment: Thanks! This is working well. And I wondered already, why I can't put "where" below of GROUP BY. It is working!